# Почему функция для проверки треугольника работает неправильно?

Tags: javascript

Существует такая функция:

```js
function isTriangle(a,b,c) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] == 0) {
      return false
    }
    for(var k = 0; k < arguments.length; k++) {
      var sum = 0;
      for(var m = 0; m < arguments.length; m++) {
        sum += arguments[m];
      }
      sum = sum - arguments[i];
      if (arguments[i] > sum) {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Она принимает три параметра, возвращает true, если можно построить треугольник с такими сторонами и возвращает false, если нельзя.

Я проверил функцию, она хорошо работает, но какое-то условие задачи не соблюдено по-видимому и задачу не пропускает.

Условия:

> Implement a method that accepts 3 integer values a, b, c. The method should return true if a triangle can be built with the sides of given length and false in any other case.
>
> (In this case, all triangles must have surface greater than 0 to be
>   accepted)

.

Что я делаю не так? Задача с codewars.

Comment: Зачем использовать arguments, если параметры заданы явно? Код выглядит как будто взятый откуда-то, а не самописный.

Comment: @Adokenai, а как их перебирать тогда циклически? Код самописный, зачем мне брать чужой код?

Comment: я вообще не понял зачем циклы. Особенно самый внутренний. `sum = a + b + c`, потом из суммы вычитается один из аргументов и идёт сравнение. То есть `sum = b + c` сравнивается с `a`. Что мешает сразу сравнить a > b + c? И так все стороны. Даже на нуль проверять не нужно.

Comment: @Adokenai, Да, может самый внутренний и лишний, но ваше сравнение не сработает.
Т.к. мне надо сравнивать не только первый аргумент со всеми остальными, а все по очереди.

Comment: проверка существования как делается? По алгоритму вижу, что каждая из длин сторон треугольника должна быть меньше или равна сумме длин двух других. И что делает цикл с индексом k?

Comment: Первый цикл берет все цифры по очереди, второй цикл тоже перебирает все цифры по очереди,и сравнивает цифру с первого цикла с суммой цифр двух других. Логично предположить, что сумма двух других цифр будет равняться всей сумме - проверяемое число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно проверить что ни одна из стороны не являться нулем, и чтобы сумма двух меньших сторон была больше чем самая большая из сторон.
К примеру треугольник со сторонами 1, 2, 3 не может существовать, это будет линия. Ваш вариант возвращает тру

```
isTriangle(1,2,3) // true (не верно)
```

Мое решение:

```
const isTriangle = (...args) => {
    // Ищем ноль
    if (args.some(n => n <= 0)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Сортируем по убыванию
    const [a, b, c] = args.sort((x, y) => y - x);
    // Сравнение
    return a > b + c;
}
```

Comment: В принципе мое решение тоже работает, только надо было поправить чуть чуть, не >, а >=